# Cannot import timestamp column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to import data from one table into another, but I get this error message

> Failure inserting into the read-only column

I found [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=88214), but I couldn't find any "ignore" in `Edit Mapping`.

I enabled `Enabled Identity Insert`.

Now I get this error message.

> Attempting insertion into the row version column "ts". Cannot insert into a row version column.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thank you

Comment: What column is throwing the error? Is it actually your identity column? Any column can be set read only. Maybe your time stamps are automatically generated? If you are using SQL Server, you can try running sp_help on the table to give you an idea about how its set up.

Comment: no it is not identity column, it is just timestamp column

Comment: You can't update a timestamp column (it's called rowversion from 2012). It automatically updates when any other column is updated. You will have to insert your data excluding the TS and it will populate itself.

Comment: @nnmmss then I guess you have your answer? You can try making the column r/w, but since I am assuming you didnt set up the schema, you probably should not. *edit* actually you probably can just skip inserting on that column, since it will auto-update. If you are worried about making a mistake, take a temp copy of the table and try your query against it to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found it . There is "ignore" . if i click on destination in front of ts column , there is one ts option and ignore option . by choosing ignore option , there would be no error